# Google Fusion Tables OR logical operator

Tags: google-fusion-tables, or-operator

I am planning to use checkboxes to filter search results from my Google Fusion Tables Map. I want an OR operator to be implemented in my query. I tried to look for solutions and I found this [page](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference). It only lists these operators: `>, <, >=, <=, = and LIKE, MATCHES (equivalent to LIKE), STARTS WITH, ENDS WITH, CONTAINS, CONTAINS IGNORING CASE, DOES NOT CONTAIN, NOT EQUAL TO, IN`.

I need an OR operator. I need to retrieve rows that contain a series of characters. First, it will look for columns that have a Rating equivalent to 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. And then look for columns that have Price equivalent to $, $$, $$$, $$$$, $$$$$.

Any alternative ways to do this?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=709 - https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=49

Comment: I've already seen these pages. Are you telling me to vote and request for the `OR` feature? I cannot see a solution there.

Comment: 1. there is no OR. 2. if you look at those enhancement requests they are marked either WontFix or Available. 3. IN is the implemented solution.